# How Laplace-Dirichlet operator can be found numerically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, laplacian, greens-function

I come from an engineering background and would like to learn about Laplace-Dirichlet operator, which I came across in a couple of [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338117/62050) on math.stackexchange.com.

Could someone kindly help me understand/interpret what we mean by the following statement, which was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338117/62050):

> Let $A = -\Delta$ be the Laplace-Dirichlet operator, $D(A) = H_0^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a bounded domain. It is known that there exists a Green's function for $A$, i.e. $G \colon L^2(\Omega) \to D(A)$ such that $Av = f \Longleftrightarrow v = Gf$.

I would be thankful to have some references to read and learn more and about this very interesting topic.

In fact, I have a bounded 3D triangulated surface whose vertices have known value of a function $g$. The region inside the surface is a subset of a larger domain whose field is harmonic. The surface is filled with points and I wanted to see if with the Laplace-Dirichlet operator I can relate the boundary points to the points inside the surface, and if so, how this can be found. Thank you in advance.

*Update*: I know how this can be done with a finite element method and I already implemented it. However, I would like to learn more about the Green's function approach.

Comment: It is a rather standard numerical problem with finite elements.

Comment: @Ian: Thank you for your comment. I know how this can be done with FEM. However, I would like to learn more about the Green's function approach.

Comment: The two are really one and the same, to numerically construct the Green's function one would fix a finite dimensional subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$ and construct the solutions to the problem for basis elements of that subspace using FEM and then use superposition. In general there is not an easy way to construct $G$ as convolution against some nice kernel.

Comment: @Ian: Does it require using harmonic basis functions or any basis function would work?

Comment: You can use whatever basis elements are convenient. Note though that the basis I'm talking about is a basis for the space that $f$ (the inhomogeneity) comes from.

Comment: @Ian: Could you please refer me to an example in which $G$ is constructed?